# ajax post size limitation or server limitation

Tags: javascript, php, json, ajax, post

Upload large files using PHP well done. I set the value of upload_max_filesize and post_max_size in php.ini :

`upload_max_filesize = 64M`

`post_max_size = 64M`

But while large files can not be loaded using Ajax. Less than 5 KB file to be uploaded correctly with Ajax.

For large files I get the following error in my console:

**Object {readyState: 4, responseText: "", status: 200, statusText: "OK"}**

How do I upload large files using the code below?

My ajax code:

```
$("#submit-edit-order").click(function () {

    //*****get data input
    var formData = new FormData();
    formData.append('action', 'update_order');
    formData.append('order_id', $('input[name=order_id]').val());
    formData.append('customer_name', $('input[name=customer_name]').val());
    formData.append('customer_id', $('input[name=customer_name]').data("cid"));
    formData.append('date', $('input[name=date]').val());
    formData.append('order_status', $('#order_sataus').find(":selected").val());
    formData.append('total_price', $('input[name=totalprice]').val().replace(/,/g, ''));
    formData.append('quits', $('input[name=quits]').val().replace(/,/g, ''));
    formData.append('desc', $('#desc').val());
    formData.append('desc2', $('#desc2').val());

    $.each($("input[type=file]"), function (i, obj) {
        $.each(obj.files, function (j, file) {
            formData.append('orderpic[]', file);
        });
    });

    //ajax start and ajax complatet
    ajax_loading();

    $.ajax({
        url: "../../includes/ajax/ajax.php",
        data: formData,
        processData: false,
        contentType: false,
        type: 'POST',
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function (response) {
            if (response.type == 'error') {
                output = '<div class="alert alert-danger" style="margin-top:12px;">' + response.text + '</div>';
            } else {
                location.reload();
                output = '<div class="alert alert-success" style="margin-top:12px;">' + response.text + '</div>';
            }
            $("section").find("#results").html(output).fadeIn('slow');
        },error: function(data){
            console.log(data);
        }
    });
});
```

PHP code:

```
if($_POST['action']=='update_order'){        
    $order_id = $db->escape($_POST['order_id']);
    $customer_id = $db->escape($_POST['customer_id']);

    $date = explode("/", $_POST['date']);
    $date = jDateTime::toGregorian($date[0], $date[1], $date[2]);
    $date = $date[0]."/".$date[1]."/".$date[2];

    $status = $_POST['order_status'];
    $total_price = $_POST['total_price'];
    $quits = $_POST['quits'];
    $desc = $_POST['desc'];
    $desc2 = $_POST['desc2'];

    //file settings
    $files = array();
    $uploaddir = '../../uploads/orders/';

    for($i=0; $i<count($_FILES['orderpic']['name']); $i++) {
        //Get the temp file path
        $tmpFilePath = $_FILES['orderpic']['tmp_name'][$i];

        //Make sure we have a filepath
        if ($tmpFilePath != "") {
            //Setup our new file path
            $time = time();
            $ext = pathinfo($_FILES['orderpic']['name'][$i], PATHINFO_EXTENSION);
            //$FilePath = $uploaddir . $time .'.'. $ext;
            $FilePath = $uploaddir . $time. basename($_FILES['orderpic']['name'][$i]);

            //Upload the file into the temp dir
            if(move_uploaded_file($tmpFilePath, $FilePath)){
                $resizeObj = new resize($FilePath);
                $resizeObj -> resizeImage(200, 350, 'portrait');
                $newFilePath = $uploaddir ."200_350". $time. basename($_FILES['orderpic']['name'][$i]);
                $resizeObj -> saveImage($newFilePath, 100);
                unlink($FilePath);
                $files[] = "200_350". $time. basename($_FILES['orderpic']['name'][$i]);
            }
        }
    }

    $files = implode("|", $files);

    $data = array(
        "user_id"=>$customer_id,
        "productImgLink"=>$files,
        "totalPrice"=>$db->escape($total_price),
        "quits"=>$db->escape($quits),
        "orderDesc"=>$db->escape($desc),
        "orderDesc2"=>$db->escape($desc2),
        "status"=>$db->escape($status),
        "date"=>$db->escape($date)
    );

    $db->where("order_id",$order_id);
    $res = $db->update("orders",$data);
    if (!$res) {
        $output = json_encode(array('type'=>'error', 'text' => 'fail'));
        die($output);
    } else {
        $output = json_encode(array('type'=>'message', 'text' => 'Done.'));
        die($output);
    }
}
```

Comment: We need to see your PHP code. What server side error do you get when sending a large file?

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan I added PHP code.

Comment: Can use chunk uploads if size is problem. See plupload for example